# How can I retrieve the LDAP server certificate for Windows 2008 and 2003 global catalog servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, ldap, domain-controller

Windows Server 2008 | Windows Server 2003

I want to leverage LDAPS on a linux appliance.  The vendor requires the server certificate for my Windows 2008 | Windows 2003 global catalog servers so it can initiate secure calls to TCP/3269 (and perhaps TCP/636). For security purposes, they don't implicitly trust self-signed certs so I need to retrieve it from the server and pre-load the public key on the appliance.

Can someone point me to instructions for how to retrieve these server certs in Windows?

Comment: Are you running your own Certificate Authority?

Comment: ..and if you aren't, are you able to load multiple keys to trust?  Each domain controller has a different one.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I am able to load multiple keys to trust

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I *highly* recommend installing an Enterprise root CA, as alluded to in the comments, because it makes certificate management loads easier.  You can even script or configure automatic certificate requests and issuance policies, in addition to having a central source for certificates.

Having said that, the procedure for retrieving a machine certificate is fairly straightforward.

Log onto the machine in question.  Open the Microsoft Management Console (`MMC.exe`).  Go to `Add/Remove Snap-in...`.  Select `Certificates`, `Add ->`.  At the pop-up dialogue, select the `Computer account` radio button, hit `Next >` and select the `Local Computer` radio button and hit `Finish` (should be selected by default).

Click `OK`, and expand `Certificates`.  the one you're looking for should be under a subfolder of `Personal` called `Certificates`, and if multiple are present, should be the one with the machine name in it, of Template type `Computer`, assuming a default certificate deployment configuration.  See the screenshot below.

[image: Certmgr.msc]